# How to resolve error when trying to install farmhash

Tags: javascript, hash

I want to [install and use farmhash](https://github.com/google/farmhash). But I'm getting the following error.

> ./node_modules/farmhash/index.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve './build/Release/farmhash' in '/path/to/my_project/node_modules/farmhash'

Steps to recreate.

At the command line, I did

```
yarn add farmhash
```

Then imported using

```
import farmhash from 'farmhash';
```

Then tried to use with

```
  const hash = farmhash.hash32('test');
```

I checked my node_modules directory to verify it installed to the correct location: node_node_modules/farmhash/index.js

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct this error?